# Deletion of repeated rows in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix, some rows of this matrix are repeated two times. I need to delete repeated rows to get a fullrank matrix. Can I do this with a loop?

Is there a function in MATLAB that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `unique`, with `'rows'` as a second input:

```
x = unique(x,'rows');
```

Or:

```
[~, idx] = unique(x,'rows');
y = x(sort(idx),:);
```

The second approach lets you keep the original order.

Comment: Thanks alot. It was so important for me. Thanks again.